# SPA с применением Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, spa

Подскажите, можно ли как-то сделать spa приложение с использованием swing?
Воспользовавшись гуглом, нашла вариант по типу "десктопное приложение, в котором отрывается .html файл". Это единственно верное решение или можно сделать как-то иначе и правильнее?
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: а почему именно swing? это выглядит странно

Comment: такое условие в тз :(